# mysql_secure_installation doesnt set root password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 `(Server version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 (Ubuntu))` and have done a fresh mysql installation. I've used mysql_secure_installation and set a root password. However when I then go (logged in as root) mysql -u root -p and enter a blank password I am still able to login to the MySQL server. I've done flush privileges, I've tried [Unable to set mysql root password](https://serverfault.com/questions/177921/unable-to-set-mysql-root-password) and I notice a similar (but unanswered) issue here: [mysql_secure_installation on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't set the root pass](https://serverfault.com/questions/942725/mysql-secure-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-set-the-root-pass).

Why would MySQL not store/save the root password? Interestingly if I try to connect as a non-root user I am not able to connect with empty OR the password.

Comment: Do you have a `~/.my.cnf` with the credentials in it in the `/root` location?  What if you set your root password within the mysql context?  Did you restart mysql after it?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that MySQL 5.7 now allows a user of the same name to access MySQL if the authentication type is "auth_socket". I'm personally not a fan - so the solution was found here:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/